# Xposed: hooking process of checking user's password entered on lockscreen?

Tags: android, xposed, xposed-framework

I am developing my own xposed module, and it will interfere the process of verifying the password user had entered, and then do some stuff.

Which method and from which package should i hook? I tried to hook `checkPassword()` method from `com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils`, but it didn't work. Log says, that this method wasn't found

So which method should I hook with Xposed if i try to interfere the process of checking user's password entered on lockscreen?

Comment: There are various ways to enforce that the user has to enter the lock screen password (or perform a biometric authentication). A very common way is to create entries in the `AndroidKeystore` and add a flag that every time the entry is used a user authentication is required. If you encounter this in your app you would have to hook the entry creation process and remove the authentication flag, because once created the entry can't be changed. But you have to check the APK file when the authentication is performed. To trace execution I recommend `frida-trace` to you.

Comment: My main goal is to override method which checks if user entered right password on the lockscreen. This module should let you to enter the system with different passwords, and these passwords may call different actons. For example, user enters one of emergency passwords, and then the phone delete some apps, folders and files defined by user, and still let him enter the system, even though he didn't enter right password

Comment: I am not sure if you can do that with Xposed. The code that checks user password is not executed within the process of an app, instead there is one central daemon which does provide this functionality. If I am not mistaken that should be the "gatekeeper" as Google calls it, and most likely it is a native not a Java/Dalvik process, so Xposed can't modify it's functionality. You should start reading the code of AOSP to get the details how lock screen auth works.

Comment: Well, there were two apps with similar functionality: PINshortcuts (https://github.com/hamzahrmalik/PINshortcuts), and LockScreen Tweakbox. I tried to use code from the first one, but unfortunately, it didn't work (log says method not found). Second app is not open source. Anyway, considering the fact that some guys made something in the past that i want to make, I have a hope that still there is a way to do it. Thanks for your answers, I will continue my search.

Comment: PINshortcuts is 8 years old. At that time Android was a bit different. And where the code is located that handles the lockscreen UI I don't know. You can download the system apks of your phone and try to decompile them using Jadx/apktool to find the UI code.